# Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Prefix' in table 'dbo.AspNetUsers' is specified more than once

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm getting this error message every time I try and update the database.  It's very strange since when I look at my table in the migration it's only there once.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                Prefix = c.String(nullable:true),
                FirstName = c.String(nullable:false,maxLength:250),
                LastName = c.String(nullable:false,maxLength:250),
                Suffix = c.String(nullable: true),
                Email = c.String(maxLength: 250),
                EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = c.String(),
                SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");
```

If you have any ideas please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Entity framework there are 4 strategies  for Database Initialization 
1)CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
2)DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
3)DropCreateDatabaseAlways
4)Custom DB Initializer
 As I think you have chosen 1st strategy(CreateDatabaseIfNotExists) and you may move 2nd strategy(DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges).

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I needed to do is:

> Blockquote
>   Run the Add-Migrations command with the -IgnoreChanges flag. Then run Update-Database again.

See this thread:

[Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'StripeRecipientId' in table 'dbo.Foos' is specified more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845336/column-names-in-each-table-must-be-unique-column-name-striperecipientid-in-ta)

Answer (score -1):

If it's "already there once" as you say, perhaps you need to Alter the table instead of Create it. You can't create something that already exists?

Unless I read this wrong.